# Web Essentials 2012 less import

Tags: import, visual-studio-2012, less, web-essentials

Have 2 files, i want to import variables stylesheet to second file, but in 1st case i get *incorrect syntax* errors in preview mode and in 2nd case i get *undeclared variable* error. Anyway both cases compile correct.

### 1st case with preview mode error:

*variables.less*:

```
@color-background: rgb(0, 0 , 0);
```

*style1.less*:

```
@import 'variables.less';
div
{
    color:@color-background;
}
```

### 2nd case with undeclared variable error:

*variables.less*:

```
html{color:red;}
@color-background: rgb(0, 0 , 0);
```

*style1.less*:

```
html{color:red;}
@import 'variables.less';
div
{
    color:@color-background;
}
```

`html{color:red}` is just fix for preview mode. it could any valid html.

Problem is that i could start file only with html tag for getting preview mode, but not comment or import directive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the LESS editor in Web Essentials. To get around it, always put your @import directives at the top of the document.

The issue was triggered because you had: html{color:red;} before the @import directive.

This issue is going to be fixed in an upcoming release of Web Essentials. No date yet, though.

Comment: weird, `@import` doesn't work at all for me (preview error, no compilation).  I have all of my LESS in one file :<